# PHP search with multiple hits

Tags: php

This is **file1.php**:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<?php
$path_to_check = '';
$needle = $_POST['query'];

foreach(glob($path_to_check . '*.xml') as $filename)
{
    foreach(file($filename)as $fl)
    {
    if(strpos($fl, $needle)!==false)
    {
      $_SESSION["hit"] = $filename;
    }
    }
}
header('Location: file2.php');
?>
```

The search is working and returning the name of the file where searchword is found as a variable $_SESSION["hit"] = $filename;

However if the searchword is found in multiple files it will not work. Then I would need to go to another page file1b.php (or file1b.html) where the multiple files will be listed. Then from there do a choice to get to file2.php.

How could it be done?

Comment: you can store an array in session. just create an empty array on  $_SESSION["hit"] and push every hit to that array :)

Comment: Use an array and loop thru it in the next file: `$_SESSION["hit"][] = $filename;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `$_SESSION['hit']` an array of all the filenames with a match.

```
$_SESSION['hit'] = array();
foreach(glob($path_to_check . '*.xml') as $filename)
{
    foreach(file($filename)as $fl)
    {
        if(strpos($fl, $needle)!==false)
        {
            $_SESSION["hit"][] = $filename;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then print the filenames with a simple loop.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['hit'] as $filename) {
    echo $filename . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I would add that its overkill to loop through all lines of file.  Just `strpos` on `file_get_contents` maybe.

Comment: Good point. I used `break` so it will stop searching once it finds a matching line. The optimal method would be to use `while ($f1 = fgets($fp))` so you don't have to read the entire file into memory in the first place.

Comment: When I add 'echo $_SESSION["hit"][];' in the end it just returns one filename - not all filenames - eventhough the searchword occurs in more than one file. I also tried 'echo $array();' but it gave nothing.

Comment: You can't echo an array, use `var_dump($_SESSION['hit'])`.

Comment: `echo $_SESSION["hit"][];` is not even valid syntax, you should get an error from that. `[]` without an index inside it is only allowed in an assignment.

Comment: Yes, that gave the full array: 'array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "1.xml" [1]=> string(5) "2.xml" } ' . Is there a way to get only the filenames printed out?

Comment: Write a loop that prints them. This is really basic stuff.

Comment: foreach($_SESSION['hit'] as $value){
     print $value."\n";
 }

Comment: Thanks for your help Barmar:-)